# Javascript chrome extension content scripts

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, manifest

I am developing a chrome extension that involves many javascript scripts. In my chrome extension manifest, I am trying to set a script to run on a certain URL. I have gotten one URL to work with a script, but if I try and add another permission for a different javascript file nothing happens. Is my syntax or code wrong?

```html
{
  "name": "test",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "version": "1.5",
  "browser_action": {"default_icon": "icon_16.png"},
  "icons" : {
  "128": "icon_128.png", "16": "icon_16.png"},   
"description": "test.",
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["*://solecarts.com/monitor/run.html*", "*://www.solecarts.com/monitor/run.html*"],
      "js": ["query.js"],
   
 "matches": ["*://solecarts.com/monitor/shopify.html*", "*://www.solecarts.com/monitor/shopify.html*"],
      "js": ["shopify.js"]
 }
  ], "permissions": [
    "tabs", "*://solecarts.com/*", "*://solecarts.com/*",
   "http://*/*",
      "https://*/*"
  ]
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrong syntax. Let me re-indent your code, with comments:

```
"content_scripts": [ // An array
  {                  // An object inside this array
                     // Properties of that object
    "matches": [
       "*://solecarts.com/monitor/run.html*",
       "*://www.solecarts.com/monitor/run.html*"
    ],
    "js": ["query.js"],
                     // Same properties within the same object?
    "matches": [
       "*://solecarts.com/monitor/shopify.html*",
       "*://www.solecarts.com/monitor/shopify.html*"
    ],
    "js": ["shopify.js"]
  }
],
```

Instead, it should be an array containing two separate objects:

```
"content_scripts": [
  {
    "matches": [
       "*://solecarts.com/monitor/run.html*",
       "*://www.solecarts.com/monitor/run.html*"
    ],
    "js": ["query.js"]
  }, {
    "matches": [
       "*://solecarts.com/monitor/shopify.html*",
       "*://www.solecarts.com/monitor/shopify.html*"
    ],
    "js": ["shopify.js"]
  }
],
```

Do note that comments are not allowed in JSON format. First snippet was just informational.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need to separate the two content script objects from each other. Try this:

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "version": "1.5",
  "browser_action": {"default_icon": "icon_16.png"},
  "icons" : {
    "128": "icon_128.png",
    "16": "icon_16.png"
  },   
  "description": "test.",
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "*://solecarts.com/monitor/run.html*",
        "*://www.solecarts.com/monitor/run.html*"
      ],
      "js": ["query.js"]
    },
    {
      "matches": [
        "*://solecarts.com/monitor/shopify.html*",
        "*://www.solecarts.com/monitor/shopify.html*"
      ],
      "js": ["shopify.js"]
    }
  ],
  "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "*://solecarts.com/*",
    "*://solecarts.com/*",
    "http://*/*",
    "https://*/*"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Beat you by 7 seconds! _Ha-ha!_

Comment: @Erik Gillespie Thank you for the help!